# Extract name, address and phone number from some web pages using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I've written a script in Python using the `multiprocessing` module to scrape values from web pages (one page per subprocess). As I'm very new to `multiprocessing`, I'm not sure whether I did everything in the right way. ***It works without error, though***.

Here goes the full script:

```
import requests 
from lxml.html import fromstring
from multiprocessing import Pool

link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={}"

def create_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    tree = fromstring(response)
    for title in tree.cssselect("div.info"):
        name = title.cssselect("a.business-name span")[0].text
        try:
            street = title.cssselect("span.street-address")[0].text
        except IndexError: street = ""
        try:
            phone = title.cssselect("div[class^=phones]")[0].text
        except IndexError: phone = ""
        print(name, street, phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = [link.format(page) for page in range(1,4)]
    with Pool(4) as p:
        p.map(create_links, links)
```

Any idea to make it more robust will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you intending to include page 4? If so, you need to change the range's (exclusive) stop value to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Proper use of a `Pool p` should include `p.close()` and `p.join()` (in this order).

Cases of the websites not responding should be handled. Requests should have a timeout, the timeout exception is caught, and non-200 should be handled as well.

Other than that, the script is correct for a one time extract of a few pages, but will need to be extended if you intend to produce a high volume daemon. If that is the case, usage of `Pool` can be questionnable and has multiple alternatives, such as using Scrapy framework scheduler or using a celery broker for high-level handling of workers (this will avoid your workers to crash entirely on exceptions, among a few other benefits).

Answer (score 1):

You've (manually?) escaped your query params in your URL string. This is OK, and technically a few nanoseconds faster, but less legible than the alternative:

```
requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search',
             params={'search_terms': 'coffee',
                     'geo_location_terms': 'Los Angeles, CA',
                     'page': page})
```

Then, rather than calling `format`, you simply pass in the `page` parameter.